# How to implement exit on Double back pressed in fragment [Android]

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to implement double back pressed in one of my FRAGMENT (NOT MainActivity) my app
I have written this code but its not working.

this is my fragment :

```
public class DashBoard extends Fragment {
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dashboard, container, false);
 rootView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    rootView.requestFocus();
    rootView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {


            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

                if (back_pressed++ > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                    Log.d("Time backpressed..if", "" + back_pressed + 2000);
                    Log.d("Time system..if", "" + System.currentTimeMillis());
                    getActivity().finish();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Press once again to exit!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    back_pressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    Log.d("Time backpressed..else", "" + back_pressed);
                    Log.d("Time system..else", "" + System.currentTimeMillis());
                }
}

                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

any suggestions..

Comment: Just create an interface to your main activity and have the key event trigger a method in your main activity to close the application.

Comment: What's back_pressed in back_pressed++ > System.currentTimeMillis()?
Does the code inside executes?

Comment: Not an answer, but for posterity: As a general rule this isn't a great behavior to add. If at all possible the app should be able to exit and reload where it was fast enough that requiring the user to confirm with an extra step shouldn't be worth it. There are exceptions if it makes no sense to resume the user where they left off, but those are rare.

Answer (score 2):

This code should put in `MainActivity` and I assume your first page fragment name is `HomeFragment`

```
boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (isInHomeFragment() && !doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
        Toast.makeText(this, "press double tap to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
            }
        }, 2000);
    } else if (isInHomeFragment() ) {
        finishAffinity();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

private boolean isInHomeFragment() {
    for (Fragment item : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
        if (item.isVisible() && "HomeFragment".equals(item.getClass().getSimpleName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you're giving backpressed the time in millis in the else, and then when you click again you add 1 millisecond to your backpressed, but you probably waited more than 1 millisecond in pressing back again, so your backpressed will still not be higher than the new current time millis, so it will always go into the else.

You should add the current time plus 2000 or 3000 ( 2 or 3 seconds) to your backpressed in else, and then compare it with the new time.

After the comments and your answer, please try this.

```
public class DashBoard extends Fragment {
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dashboard, container, false);
rootView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
rootView.requestFocus();
long back_pressed=System.currentTimeMillis();// Backpressed initialized //
rootView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
         if (back_pressed++ >     System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                Log.d("Time backpressed..if", "" + back_pressed);
                Log.d("Time system..if", "" + System.currentTimeMillis());
                getActivity().finish();
          else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Press once again to exit!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                back_pressed = (System.currentTimeMillis()+2000);
                Log.d("Time backpressed..else", "" + back_pressed);
                Log.d("Time system..else", "" + System.currentTimeMillis());
         }
         return true;
     }
        return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: what you suggested me .that i did but doesn't work for me

Comment: Can you update your code with the new changes? And where do you declare and initialize the back_pressed variable?

Comment: Updated my answer with an snippet of code you could try

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DashBoard extends Fragment {
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dashboard, container, false);
rootView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
rootView.requestFocus();
long back_pressed=System.currentTimeMillis();`//****this my intialization of back_pressed***//
rootView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
 @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
 if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {`if (back_pressed++ > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                Log.d(
                Log.d("Time system..if", "" + System.currentTimeMillis());
                getActivity().finish();
} else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Press once again to exit!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                back_pressed = (System.currentTimeMillis()+2000);
                Log.d("Time backpressed..else", "" + back_pressed);
                Log.d("Time system..else", "" + System.currentTimeMillis());
            }
 return true;
        }
        return false;
  }
});
```